# Sanitize string to be used as directory name

Tags: java, android

How do you sanitize string to make sure it will be valid to be used as a directory name?

I have tried searching as well, but can't find good information what characters are good or not to be used as directory name.

Comment: @BlackFrog my question is for directory name, while those link are for file name, are the same rules applies for both?

Comment: Directory names and file names have the same restriction. There is no difference.

Comment: @johnvantes In my opinion you should rethink what you're trying to do. It's not good to try to fix a path that has been given to you wrong, how can you possibly trust any of the characters of a wrong path ? Don't try to recover from failure, fail safe (message) or fail hard (exception)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Simply by trying to create it :

```
File directory = new File(path);
directory.mkdirs();
```

If it fails, it will throw an exception that you can handle appropriately.

Comment: thanks, but my question would be what to do if the trial is failing.

Comment: Totally depends on your application, what should it do ?

Comment: It should then sanitize the failing `path` string so that it will be a valid directory name.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty bad idea. How do you sanitize `gre*--\\//*..02fezfgoçà"\\è-$ù!` ? You should not try to recover from this, either you print an error message or you just fail

Comment: Hmm. You have a good point. This is what my app does. It loads a video. Then it produces images based on that. Then it automatically saves the produced images on a directory with a name based on the video name. Therefore I need to sanitize the video name.

Comment: I see. I think the only unallowed character is the slash. My answer is not particularly good for your use case as it might do weird things with a name like `na/me`. Is the name the only part of the path you don't have control over ? By the way if the video already exists as a file on the device, then you know its name is valid

Comment: Yes, as the directory name should be automatically generated. _By the way if the video already exists as a file on the device, then you know its name is valid_ thanks!

Comment: Do the comments answer the question ? If so, I will edit my answer to reflect this. Otherwise, do you stll need to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Id use ASCII values 48 - 57, and 97-122 (you can use capital letters too if you expect users to look at the directory paths) in order to be completely safe.